# laravel view pdf file from s3 in new tab

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-8

how to open pdf file from s3 in a new tab ?

the following code download the file .. but i want to view it in the browser

store method in controller

```php
public function store(Request $request)
  { 
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'leg_number'    => 'required',
        'leg_year'      => 'required',
        'leg_title'     => 'required',
        'leg_type_id'     => 'required',
        'leg_published' => 'required',
        'file'          => 'required',
      ]);

      $name = $request->leg_number . '_' . $request->leg_year . '.pdf';
      $path = 'documents/' . $name;
      Storage::disk('s3')->put($path, $request->file, 'public');
      $validated['leg_path'] = $name;
      $document = Legislation::create($validated);
  }
```

show method in controller

```php
public function showLegislation(Legislation $legislation)
  {

   $content = Storage::disk('s3')->get('documents/' . $legislation->leg_path);

    $header = [
      'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
      'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="' . $legislation->leg_path . '"'
    ];

    return Response::make($content, 200, $header);
  }
```

route

```php
Route::get('legislation/show/{legislation}', [LegislationController::class, 'showLegislation'])->name('legislation.show');
```

blade

```php
<a href="{{ route('admin.legislation.show', $leg->id) }}" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: You want the pdf to be displayed in the browser instead of downloading it?

Comment: yes .. thats exactly what i want

Comment: have you tried setting the `Content-Disposition` header to `inline`?

Comment: i tried .. but the same thing ... downloading

Comment: I figured out that the problem related to chrome browser ... because the firefox open the file in a new tab as i want !!

Answer (score 1):

Finally ... it's `internet dwonlaod manager` that capture the link and dwonload the file.. if i disable it .. everything works fine